# Do MS monthly security rollups include previous monthly rollups?

Tags: windows, updates

do Microsoft monthly quality security rollups include previous-monthly releases? For example, if you skip march rollup and install april's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows 10, updates are cumulative. In October 2016, all patches to Windows 7 and 8.1 became cumulative as with Windows 10. The ability to download and install individual updates were removed as existing updates were transitioned to this model. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Update)

I interpret this as if you will get March's update too if you install April's.